# Improve update SQL query performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've an SQL database to contain stock bars downloaded from Yahoo!. I'm trying to create some indicators to analyze these stocks (i.e. Simple Moving Average). I am concerned with the performances of my query, which is simply `UPDATE @stockname SET SMA = @value WHERE id = @n` . To update 2000 rows it takes 2 minutes. I tried with a stored procedure but the result is almost the same.

```
for (int i = 0; i < closing_prices.Count - length; i++)
{
   double signalValue signalValue = Selector.SignalProcessor(Signal,
                                        closing_prices.GetRange(i, length), length);
    //Write the value into the database
    string location = Convert.ToString(i + length + 1);
    this.UpdateWithSingleCondition("_" + Instrument, columnName,
         signalValue.ToString(), "id", location, "=", sql_Connection);
}
```

This cycle calls the stored procedure to update the column SMA each time a new value is generated. Is there any possibility to put directly the entire column into the database? I think this can save time. Anyway updating 500 rows in 2 min sounds very slow.

Could you tell me how to improve the execution time of my query?

Comment: Is `@stockname` a table variable? Did you declare a `PRIMARY KEY` on `id`?

Comment: How did you isolate the performance issue to the database?  There's the call to Selector.SignalProcessor - could that routine be causing some of the delay?  Also, posting a description of the relevant tables in your database would be a good thing.

Comment: Bob, thanks for your comment, I'm still learning how to code using SQL, so I'll try to call Selector.SignalProcess to evaluate the performances. My database is very plain, I've a MasterTable which stores all the instruments in the database, so name, exchange, currency etc. and I have one table for each instrument in the database, which has 5 columns to store opening/closing prices/volumes of daily stocks bars retrieved from yahoo and more columns depending on which signals I want to generate for that instrument ie. SMA with length of 20/30/50 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a stored proc that receives a string. This string is an XML or delimeted string.

Then use one of the many string to table functions floating around

- (delimeted string) http://blogs.x2line.com/al/articles/150.aspx
- (xml) http://kennyshu.blogspot.com/2007/12/convert-xml-file-to-table-in-sql-2005.html

and convert the string into a temp table.

Then perform a insert from the temp to the destination table.

This way you make one call to the DB server and avoid chatter. Its a LOT faster than multiple calls.

Avoid table parameters since you cant call em from code.

Comment: Quick update: I moved the structure from single thread to multi-threads. Now I'm able to run up to 1k updates per second in 20 distincts threads. I still don't understand why mt works better than a single thread but that's my result.

Comment: That would probably indicate the bottleneck was in the code and not the update. Possibly when you are retrieving the prices (SignalProcessor)? Doing this asynchronously will effectively setup the call to the bottleneck and move onto the next iteration. If this is the case then there is possibly a faster solution if you can get all your movement data in a single bulk query, then do a single bulk update (Obviously if this is even needed).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing values out one at a time, perhaps you could use a stored proc with [table valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) to ship the data from your app to the DB in a single op then [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) the data into your table, saving on a lot of round-tripping.

Comment: Not the issue. I do a LOT more updates during that time. 500 updates in 120 seconds is slow.

Comment: You're missing indexes somewhere then. Are there FK relationships that you haven't told us about?

Comment: Yes, that would be a likely culprit. Without idnices the table scan will kill him.

Comment: Well that is the idea that came to my mind. I'm able to create an entire column cause I've all the values needed, but I don't know how to merge that. Can you elaborate this please?

Comment: Guys, is there a function to split strings in SQL? Maybe I can pass the entire list of values to my stored procedure as TEXT and parsing it to avoid too much transactions. Anyway the loop would be still in place, but at least I reduced the amount of connections to the server.

Comment: @Antonio, as @TomTom has said, there's something else that is slowing things down considerably. I think that your efforts would be better spent studying your schema, the relationships and indexes on your data. The extremely slow updates would indicate that even if you do batch the updates into a single operation, the DB will still groan when it comes to actually updating the data. As mentioned before, are you sure that everything is correctly indexed? What is the actual SQL running at the DB? What does the execution plan look like?

Comment: @spender, as I said I have no relationships in my database, single tables, each for every instrument. I know you can properly mod the database, but let's consider the single table for now. The updating process takes 2min for 7k rows. An index is in place, and I'm using it to retrieve the right value which needs to be updated. So probably is an hw problem.(ie I tried with adventureworks database, and the results are the same...)

Answer (score 1):

Analyze your performance. You must have SOME bottleneck. Your update count is really low. You should easily be able to do 10-30 updates per second which would translate to a lot more in 2 minutes.... and that is on a stock computer, not even one worth a database (which would mean many fast discs).

Do a performance analysis on sql server and find out your bottlenecks. You have all indices needed?

Comment: "id" is my index. Do you think I need another index? Considering that I've one table for each instrument in my database I think 1 index should be sufficient.

Comment: One table per instrument already ia a mistake... I track around 300k instrumetns (complete CME group pricing, incl a.ll options) and use only one table. I insert about 75.000 itms per second when stressing the server.

Comment: Sounds cool, but as I said I'm in the early stage of my SQL learning and developing. I don't have live data, just EOD data, so single daily bars, which are not comparable to what you're doing. Maybe I've to tell you that I'm using an home pc/standard retail pc, with an IDE HD 7.2k rpm, and not a teraflop server... ;-)

Comment: Irrelevant ;) The 10-30 updates were done on my workstation before moving the code to a server. 75.000 are not even taxing the disc subsystem.... more the network between them. It is a LOT more about knowing what you do (not individual inserts) than cpu speed at those low speeds. If you have litle data, btw., get a small 64gb SSD for the database. They are CHEAP.

Comment: TomTom, 75k updates per sec sounds like monkey speed. I've just finished a nice article about SQL performances, that talks about 35k updates per sec like a fast&furios speed. Of course they're cheap, but that's not the point, focus is acquiring more experience in SQL developing, overcoming this issues for example. Btw if you have that money please make my a wire, I promise I'll buy a new HD.

Comment: Well, let me just say that those 75k inserts happen in transactions of about 32500 items and involve bulk uploading the items to separate temp tables per table, then mass processing them. And they involve 6 discs for the data and more for the log.

Answer (score 0):

First disable external key constrains. then enable them again:

To disable "ALTER TABLE"  "WITH NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL"

To anable them, use "ALTER TABLE" together with "WITH CHECK
CONSTRAINT ALL".

Comment: That isn't the correct syntax to re-enable constraints. It leaves them untrusted. It needs to be `WITH CHECK CHECK` or something like that. I would imagine the OP just needs an index anyway.

Comment: Well I don't have any external key, each table is an alone table, there are no relashionships between tables.